# Accessing http.get data in directive

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a code that I get data of a JSON file in it using `$http.get`
. Now I wanna access the data in the custom directive that I've made !

Here is my code for the getting json file :

```
$http.get('myData.json').then(function(dataList){
    for (var i = 0; i < dataList.data.length; i++) {
        this.myData = {};
        this.myData.id = dataList.data[i].id;
        this.myData.car = dataList.data[i].car;
        this.myArray.push(this.myData);
    }
});
```

And here is my code for my custom directive :

```
app.directive('dataList', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'data-list.html'
    };
});
```

It will be much more better if I could access the `myArray` data in the directive as a function and etc ...

Comment: are you getting the data in the controller?

Comment: That isn't good use `http` service in directive. i think @devqon's  and @Mistalis's answer is good.

Comment: @hadiJz The `$http` call is **not** in the directive.

Answer (score 2):

Add a scope variable:

```
app.directive('dataList', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: "="
        },
        templateUrl: 'data-list.html'
    };
});
```

Pass it to your directive:

```
<data-list data="myArray">
```

Then you can access it in your template of the directive `data-list.html`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
```

**Note**: In your `for`-loop you are resetting your `this.myData` object each time, while you push it n-times in your array. Every item in your array will therefore be an empty `{}` object, except for the last one. Also, you are using the index `i` on your new object, which seems weird to me.

Instead create a new object in your `for`-loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataList.data.length; i++) {
    var myData = {};
    myData.id = dataList.data[i].id;
    myData.car = dataList.data[i].car;

    myArray.push(myData);
}
```

Or maybe it is enough to just do `this.myArray.push(dataList.data[i])`, or even just assign the whole array: `this.myArray = dataList.data`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the following:

```
myApp.directive('dataList', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      array: '='
    },
    template: '<div ng-repeat="o in array">ID: {{o.id}}<br/>Car: {{o.car}}</div>'
  };
});
```

Here `$scope.myArray` (in your case it comes frop your `$http.get` request):

```
$scope.myArray = [
    { id: 1, car: "Car1" },
    { id: 2, car: "Car2" }, 
    { id: 3, car: "Car3" }
];
```

You can use it like this:

```
<data-list array="myArray"></data-list>
```

### [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/m99h2ubh/1/)

---

As a side note, I would suggest you to modify a bit the loop where you create `myArray`:

```
for(...) {
    this.myArray.push({id: dataList.data[i].id, car: dataList.data[i].car});
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot :)
But I wanted to make the directive with templateUrl 
BTW, thanks bro !